# obtaining the true values for two parameter gamma distribution

Tags: statistics

please i have a data set on length of stay in the hospital for two parameter gamma distribution. i want to compare moment and maximum likelihood estimation method for the distribution using mse. i was able to obtain moment estimate for alpha and beta and i was also able to obtain maximum likelihood estimate for alpha and beta. Now my question is that how do i know the true values so that i would be able to compare the two estimators. thank you in advance.

Comment: You cannot know the 'true' parameter values. That is the reason you are using estimates. // It seems you are asked to use MSE to compare MM Estimates and ML Estimates. Then the method with the smaller MSE is judged superior.

Comment: thanks BruceET but please what is the R code to be used for MSE.

Comment: I'm unclear about the exact task. Is the assignment to find a general analytic formula for MSEs of moment estimators (MMEs) for shape parameter $\alpha$ and scale parameter $\beta$ and similarly for maximum likelihood estimators (MLEs)? Of is it to use a simulation in R to get MSEs? If you check Google for 'gamma distribution parameter estimation, you might get help with analytic solutions (maybe start with the Wikipedia article on 'gamma distribution'). MLE for shape parameter based on specific data requires numeric or other approximation.

Comment: If you have access to the math stat text by Bain & Englehardt (1987, Duxbury), perhaps at a univ. library, you can find specific info about gamma MMEs in Example 9.2.4 and about MLEs in Example 9.2.12.

Comment: let me clarify it for you. From the real life data, have obtained mle of the two parameters and moment estimates of the two parameter using fitdist(),but that is not enough to make a comparison of which of the two estimator is the better. that is reason why am asking if i can obtain the true parameters value so that i can know how the estimates deviate from true values.

Comment: Unless the data are fake simulated with particular parameters and someone tells you the sim code, you cannot know the true param values. The MLEs tend to be better, but the MLE for the shape param has no formula in closed form; imust be obtained by numer methods for each dataset. The MMEs have simple formulas but larger MSEs. // Ignoring the theory, you might be able to get 4 param bootstrap CIs for the 2 params and then look for the shortest CI for each param. But you have not told me $n$, $\bar X$, $S,$ etc. With that info I could show R code bootsr CIs of MMEs. But for MLEs it's too messy.

Comment: thanks. the data sample size is 269, mean is  7.078067 and  70.55732. what is the r code for obtaining the mse or the total deviation │(β ̂-β)/β│+│(α ̂-α)/α│

Comment: Do you have the sample SD $S$?

Comment: yes the sd is 8.39984

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brief outline of the rationale and R code for getting parametric bootstrap 95% confidence
intervals for the unknown shape parameter $\alpha$ and scale parameter $\beta$ of
a gamma distribution based on a random sample of $n$ observations.

Let $X_1, \dots X_{269} \stackrel{iid}{\sim}\mathsf{Gamma}(\alpha, \lambda =
1/\beta),$ where $\lambda = 1/\beta$ is the rate parameter (used in R).
We seek a 95% CI for $\beta.$ The observed MME is 
$\tilde \beta_{obs} = \frac{n-1}{n}\frac{S^2}{\bar X}.$

If we knew the distribution of $V_\beta = \tilde \beta/\beta,$ we could find
constants $L_\beta$ and $U_\beta$ such that
$$.95 = P(L_\beta < V_\beta < U_\beta) = 
P\left(\frac{\tilde\beta_{obs}}{U_\beta} < \beta <\frac{\tilde\beta_{obs}}{L_\beta}\right),$$
and $(\tilde\beta_{obs}/L_\beta,\, \tilde\beta_{obs}/L_\beta)$ would be a
95% CI for $\beta.$ (Note the reversal of inequalities because of taking
reciprocals to isolate $\beta.$)

Not knowing the distribution of $V_\beta,$ we use a parametric bootstrap to 
obtain estimates $L_\beta^*$ of $L_\beta$ and $U_\beta^*$ of $U_\beta$.
Similarly for $\alpha,$ estimated by $\tilde\alpha = \bar X/\tilde\beta.$

> Entering the so-called bootstrap world, we take a large number $B$ of
>   're-samples' of size $n$ from 
>   $\mathsf{Beta}(\tilde\alpha_{obs}, 1/\tilde\beta_{obs}),$
>    temporarily using the observed estimates as proxies for the unknown parameters.
>   For each of the $B$ re-samples, we find $\tilde \alpha^*$ and $\tilde\beta^*$,
>   and from them $V_\beta^* = \tilde\beta^*/\tilde\beta_{obs}$ and
>   $V_\alpha^* = \tilde\alpha^*/\tilde\alpha_{obs}.$

Returning to the 'real world', we take quantiles .025 and .975 of the many $V_\beta^*$ to get the desired
estimates $L_\beta^*$ and $U_\beta^*$, and similarly for $L_\alpha^*$ and $U_\alpha^*.$ Thus we have parametric bootstrap 95% CIs
$(\tilde\beta_{obs}/U_\beta^*,\, \tilde\beta_{obs}/L_\beta^*)$ for $\beta$ and 
$(\tilde\alpha_{obs}/U_\alpha^*,\, \tilde\alpha_{obs}/L_\alpha^*)$ for $\alpha.$

---

In the R code below, we use `.re` for $*$, `sc` for $\beta$ `sh` for $\alpha,$
and `a` for $\bar X.$

```
set.seed(1212)
B = 10^5;  vsh.re = vsc.re = numeric(m)
n = 269;  a = 7.78;  s = 8.4
sc.obs = (n-1)*s^2/(n*a);  sh.obs = a/sc.obs
for(i in 1:B)  {
  x.re = rgamma(n, sh.obs, 1/sc.obs)
  a.re = mean(x.re);  s.re = sd(x.re)
  sc.re = (n-1)*s.re^2/(n*a.re);  sh.re = a.re/sc.re 
  vsc.re[i] = sc.re/sc.obs;  vsh.re[i] = sh.re/sh.obs  }
UL.vsc = quantile(vsc.re, c(.975,.025));  CI.sc = sc.obs/UL.vsc
UL.vsh = quantile(vsh.re, c(.975,.025));  CI.sh = sh.obs/UL.vsh
CI.sc; CI.sh
##     97.5%      2.5% 
##  6.916052 11.989209   # CI for scale 'beta' 
##     97.5%      2.5% 
##  0.6727584 1.0926581  # CI for shape 'alpha'
sc.obs;  sh.obs
## 9.035693              # Observed scale
## 0.8610297             # Observed shape
```

---

**Notes:** (1) Now that I have seen your estimates, I'm wondering if the true distribution
might be exponential instead of gamma. The shape parameter $\alpha = 1$ would
be consistent with exponential data. If you used a distribution ID procedure,
then *of course* it will get a better 'fit' using *two* parameters, shape and
scale, rather than *one*. When using distribution ID procedures, it is
always difficult to decide whether the most realistic fit is to the
family or a subfamily with only marginally worse fit.

(2) A bootstrap procedure for MLEs would require a numerical solution
for the estimate of the shape parameter to be done afresh on each passage through the loop.

(3) For bootstrapping a *location* parameter $\tau,$ one would re-sample to
obtain information about $D = \tilde\tau - \tau$ rather than $V = \tilde\tau/\tau.$

Comment: Thanks so much i really appreciate but have really gotten that, i mean how do i relate this with MLE and MME